# Android Navigation Component. How to override fragment or action for another build variant without creating new graph

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack

I have 10 flavors(build variants) in gradle and ~50 fragments as Screen.
As a result nav_graph is very big (~700 lines).
Extending some fragments is a trivial problem, i have 10% extensions for each build variant

How to override only a fragment or an action for another build variant in order to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Perhaps pull out the segments to be replaced into [nested graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs), so you can replace those individual bits in different build variants.